# In search for universal formal greetings

Tags: british-english, writing-style, email, greetings, salutations

I am dealing with a system which is supposed to autoreply to certain emails. It cannot start with 'Dear (forename)' as it cannot parse a forename from email address or original email. It also cannot start with 'Good morning/afternoon/evening' as it is not flexible enough to generate a response based on time of day besides timezones makle it even more interesting.

It's not a brilliant idea to reply to someone's email with 'Dear Sir or Madam',
So what is a universal static text greeting line, appropriate for most formal autoreplies without sounding too 'canned'.

I am based in the UK.

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want a *universal* greeting only for the UK?

Comment: If you are addressing someone on a common social, political, moral or philosophical path, you might say *Dear [Fellow Traveler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fellow_traveller)*, but then again, you might get a McCarthy-like reaction.

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want a personal greeting that a "bot" can use.

Comment: If your program is too dumb to make a personal greeting, skip it and get to the business of the message, like a telegram.  You aren't going to be fooling many with a form letter anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple *Hello*?

Or if the message is always in reply to some kind of request, you can start with *Thank you for your request.*.

IMHO, you shouldn't waste time trying to make canned emails sound too natural or folksy. Everyone knows these are automated, and it will just seem disingenuous if you try to make it seem like it was written by a real person.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with someone within your own field (or engaged in a common project), you can say *Dear [Colleague](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/colleague),*

> A person with whom one works in a profession or business

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

While the term often applies to someone employed in the same organization, it is often used for others in your field at different institutions.

Answer (score 0):

Salutations!

or

Greetings!

I suppose you could also start with

It was good to hear from you!

or

We were very glad to receive your email.

or

We appreciate your taking the time to write.

Note, I am from the U.S. and can't really simulate a British style -- but hopefully these ideas will get you started.